# Codeigniter and oracle undefined constant: OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I develloping a web-based application with codeigniter and when I try to connect to my oracle entreprise 9g database the framework send me this error:

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS - assumed 'OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS'

Filename: database/DB.php

Line Number: 142
```

I tried different method to connect (classic, [oracle specific](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Oracle%3aKnown_Issues/)).
There is my config/database.php file.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=*xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx*)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=*DB_NAME*)))';
$db['default']['username'] = '*username*';
$db['default']['password'] = '*password*';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I think it's not a connection error, can you help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS` is a constant declared in the Oracle PHP [extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php). Are you sure you have that installed correctly? Is it enabled in php.ini? Can you confirm that you can connect to the database manually with [`oci_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php)?

If you don't have the extension, then you'll need to install it. There is a list of steps I generally take to debug the installation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549251/php-oracle-oci-connect-ora-12705-cannot-access-nls-data-files/6565017#6565017).

I'm not sure what the value of OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS is, but you might be able to fake it with your own define, if it comes to that.

Comment: Thank you, it came from the activation of the extension in php.ini.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: I have installed Oracle Client. And in my php.ini I have enabled:

php_oci8.dll, php_oci88_11g.dll and php_pdo_oci.dll

I checked oci_connect() function but it become "Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()".

How to fix it, please? How to install it right ?

Comment: @TienHoang Are you sure you're using the right version of php.ini, some instances of PHP have two different ini files on the same machine (I, for one, am using a Mac, which has a different ini for CLI and for Apache).

Comment: "Undefined function oci_connect" means that you do not have the OCI extension installed in any case.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: Yeah, I found my problem. I use both php_oci8.dll and php_oci8_11g.dll and it not fit my system. Thank you.