# Symfony Connect to Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, doctrine-orm, symfony

When I run the command

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force xxxxINCMSIntergrationSmartLogBundle annotation
```

I get the following error;

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                    
Notice: Use of undefined constant OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS - assumed 'OCI_COMM  
IT_ON_SUCCESS'                                                               


doctrine:mapping:import [--em [EM]] [--filter FILTER] [--force] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> <bundle> [<mapping-type>]
```

Any help on what im doing wrong?

Comment: This might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758328/codeigniter-and-oracle-undefined-constant-oci-commit-on-success

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that OCI8 is not setup correctly on your system.
You might want to read my blog on installing OCI8 on RHEL:

https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/category/oci8/

Also, read over [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html), which is also referenced in my blog.

Maybe the change needed for you is as simple as editing the php.ini file and uncommenting the extension for oci. Try a search in the php.ini file for "oci".

Answer (score 0):

Check your php oci8 dll, you need 64 bits PHP version if Oracle is 64 Bits