# ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment

Tags: oracle

The other day I got this annoying oracle error: ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified. Funny thing I wasn't trying to access NLS data files

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two possible causes:

An attempt was made to issue an ALTER SESSION statement with an invalid NLS parameter or value.

The NLS_LANG environment variable contains an invalid language, territory, or character set.

Fix:

Unset the NLS_LANG environment variable

Windows - The NLS_LANG must be unset in the Windows registry (re-named is best). Look for the NLS_LANG subkey in the registry at \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE, and rename it.

Linux/UNIX - Here you simply issue the Linux command "unset NLS_LANG"

Answer (score 15):

I have Oracle 10g XE and Windows 7. I resolved this as follows:

Go to Control panel > Regional and language options > Format and set your language.

Comment: This classify as a comment, not as a full answer

Comment: this was the only thing that worked in my case, thanks.

Comment: In windows 10: Go to "Control Panel > Region > Format", then set Format to "English (United States)", then restart your client tool (ex: oracle sql developer).

Answer (score 3):

Follow this procedure to set the NLS_LANG environment variable for Oracle databases.
To set the NLS_LANG environment variable for Oracle databases
Determine the NLS_LANG value.
In the data warehouse database, run the command
SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS

Make a note of the NLS_LANG value, which is in the format [NLS_LANGUAGE]_[NLS_TERRITORY].[NLS_CHARACTERSET].
For example: American_America.UTF8
For Windows:
Navigate to Control Panel > System and click the Advanced tab. Click Environment Variables.
In System variables section, click New.
In the Variable Name field, enter NLS_LANG.
In the Variable Value field, enter the NLS_LANG value that was returned in Step 1.
The format for the NLS_LANG value should be [NLS_LANGUAGE]_[NLS_TERRITORY].[NLS_CHARACTERSET].
For example: American_America.UTF8.
For UNIX, set the variable as shown below:
setenv NLS_LANG

For example: setenv NLS_LANG American_America.UTF8.
If your data is 7-bit or 8-bit ASCII and the Informatica Server is running on UNIX, then set
NLS_LANG _.WE8ISO8859P1
CAUTION:  Make sure you set the NLS_LANG variable correctly, as stated in this procedure, or your data will not display correctly.

Reboot the machine after creating the variable.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was creating a database adapter in the Oracle WebLogic console, solve the problem by doing the following configuration.
Windows -> control panel -> region:

1. Change the format to English (United States) date format M / d / yy and
2. Change my address to the United States.

Perform this configuration because my machine was configured with the Spanish language, then restart the computer and I worked without problems.

Comment: So in latest build of Win10, you cannot change the address from the control panel, so just change the rest and that worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me. Don't forget to restart your PC after you make the change.

Answer (score 2):

After addition of path in Environment variable of **Oracle Instant client** the Oracle **SQLPLUSW** goes to  Oracle Instant client and for that client it required to set **NLS LANG AS American_America.UTF8**

Answer (score 1):

You can also just set the NLS config in your oracle settings

Answer (score 1):

In case if above solutions not helped, can try my solution. I just replaced my latest version of `Ojdbc14.jar` to an older version `Ojdbc5.jar`. It helped me to solve my issue.

Comment: for Oracle 12C I used ojdbc7.jar, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to configure my Data Source on WebLogic 12c that was pointing to an 11g Database and I kept getting this error. I found out that WL 12c is not compatible with oracle 11g databases.
I know it is not related but I am sure someone else will find this useful.