# Error : SQLSTATE[HY000]: OCISessionBegin: ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:686)

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I have been through every post and none work for me.
I am trying to get a PDO connection set up but keep getting the below error message.

**Error : SQLSTATE[HY000]: OCISessionBegin: ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:686)**

phpinfo is indicating that all is setup properly, php.ini is configured, local key changed NLS_LANG.

Does "(ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:686)" indicates anything wrong in my settings?

Comment: You said you have been trhough some post, have you tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/7700339/1880431

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: I had renamed the value of the NLS_LANG subkey, not the name of the key itself!