# ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified Japanese NLS

Tags: java, oracle, registry, cjk, nls-lang

I have an error **ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified** upon running my program in eclipse.

Things I tried so far:

I have already tried to rename NLS_LANG subkey in the registry at \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE at the registry.

I have also set my region to Japan.

I tried to run SELECT USERENV('language') FROM DUAL;(result below)

```
+------+-------+--------+
| USERENV('language')   |
+------+-------+--------+
|JAPANESE_JAPAN.AL32UTF8|
+------+-------+--------+
```

Currently in my registry, the value data of NLS_LANG is AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252. I also changed this to JAPANESE_JAPAN.JA16SJIS but it does not work either.

Since this error was not encountered by my teammates who set up the program too and note that they didn't even set their NLS_LANG so I didn't define it in the Environment variables too, I tried it but it didn't work too.

I tried the answers in [ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700330/ora-12705-cannot-access-nls-data-files-or-invalid-environment) but so far nothing works for me.

I also tried to re install Oracle 11

Comment: Java does not use `NLS_LANG` settings, see [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643) Check your Java installation and settings in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who encountered same problem and is checking on this.

I finally found the solution by setting my default language to English(United States). Any region would suffice as long as my language is set to this.