# SQL connection using SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting this error while connecting SQL developer first time.

Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700330/ora-12705-cannot-access-nls-data-files-or-invalid-environment)

Comment: Show us what you have set in your preferences on the NLS page

Comment: problem has been solved .i have change my regional language.